# Create temp table in a STABLE stored procedure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I would like to create a temp table in a stored procedure which has a *STABLE* volatility category setted to store the result of a select for later usage in the stored procedure. At the end of the stored procedure this temp table is deallocated and i am sure that this temp table does not have any affect on the database, because as far as i know with this volatility category i ensure the optimizer that this stored procedure will not affect the database.

So i would like to do something like this:

Create a stored procedure which returns with a query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION storedproc() 
RETURNS TABLE 
(Egy TEXT,
 Ketto TEXT) 
AS $$
BEGIN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM temptable;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Create a stored procedure which is using the previous query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stablefunction() 
RETURNS TABLE 
(Egy TEXT,
 Ketto TEXT) 
AS $$
BEGIN
        -- I would like to store the results here for later usage
        CREATE TEMP TABLE buba AS select * from storedproc();

        -- Do other stuff
        -- ...
        -- Reuse the results here which was stored before

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
STABLE;
```

But when i want to execute this stored procedure as this:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
    perform stablefunction() ;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i get the following error message:

> ERROR:  CREATE TABLE AS is not allowed in a non-volatile function

Maybe this is not the intended usage of the stored procedures, but then is there a way for store the result of a query inside of the stored procedure for later usage in the same stored procedure, maybe like a handle or somethings?

Comment: Maybe you can store the results in an array of that table type? I suspect there's a better way to accomplish what you want to do anyway, but can't say without seeing the actual code.

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-volatility.html) states clearly: *A stable function cannot modify the database.* A temporary table is a part of a database as well, so you cannot create it, insert into, delete from etc. Your concept seems a bit strange but I don't want to judge it. There is a trick that allows what you want to do. Perfom all actions on the temp table using other functions that do not have to be stable. Example:

```
create or replace function create_my_temp_table()
returns void language plpgsql volatile as $$
begin
    create temp table temp_table(id int);
    insert into temp_table values (123);
end $$;

create or replace function stable_function()
returns text language plpgsql stable as $$
begin
    perform create_my_temp_table();
    return 'ok';
end $$;
```

Test:

```
select stable_function();

 stable_function 
-------------
 ok
(1 row)

select * from temp_table;

 id  
-----
 123
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, and thanks for not judging! : ) I agree maybe there is a problem with my concept, maybe its coming from my OOP background which can not be adapted in a procedural language world. The problem which i wanted to solve is that the main query is very complex and if i would want to nest selects into selects and joints it would be very complex and hard to maintain. Thanks again for your answer. :)

Comment: Using temporary tables in a function is not unusual, it can greatly facilitate the processing of data, especially in the case of very complicated queries. I do not know, however, why the function must be stable.

Comment: I would like to improve the performance for a stored procedure which will be called over and over again just with different args only for reading from the database and as far as i know the stable volatility category is exactly for this purpose which will help the optimizer and improve the performance.

Comment: This performance improvement concerns the results of a function which can be cached when the function is repeatedly executed with the same arguments. I do not know your case but I'm afraid that you pin too much hope on this optimization.